# Can I write logic in a database?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, mobile

I'm writing a Flutter app that users can buy stuff on, and I have a discount scheme like: Buy more than 10 and get 5% off, more than 20 gets 10% off etc.

And that is very easy to implement in the code. But I'd rather not hard code the discount logic, since I might want to change it later.

So is there a way I can create that logic on a database and just call it on checkout?

I thought about creating Switch Cases with variables from a database which I can then change. But then I am limited by the amount of cases I create.
i.e.:

```
int discount1 = FirebaseReference; // 5
int limit1 = FirebaseReference; // 10 (so give 5% of if more than 10 is bought)
int discount2 = FirebaseReference; // 6
int limit2 = FirebaseReference; // 20
int discount3 = FirebaseReference; // 8
int limit3 = FirebaseReference; // 30

switch(discount) { 
   case amountBought < limit1: { 
      discount1 
   } 
   break; 
  
   case amountBought >= limit1 && amountBought < limit2: { 
      discount2
   } 
   break; 

   case amountBought >= limit3: { 
      discount3
   } 
   break; 
}
```

Is there a way I can have this type of code in a database?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think directly coding that logic into the database is possible (at least in Firebase).

Maybe you meant something like [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). This way, you can just deploy new discount logics as new functions.